# Yii2 users logged out after short period, while session timeout set to 30 days

Tags: php, yii2

Yii2 Users being logged out after a short period of time while they should still logged in for 30 days.

I'm Using PHP 5.6, AWS Elastic Beanstalk and cache session, i also tried the same code on single EC2 server with DB session and file session but it didn't solve the issue.

I don't know if this point is helpful or not, when i log in on Firefox browser then close it and then re-opening the site it's opened as logged out user, i tried the same case on chrome it's keeping me as logged in user.

I've included the relevant parts of the code:

**Config**

```
'components' => [
...
'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\CacheSession',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableSession' => true,
        'autoRenewCookie' => true,
        'authTimeout' => 657567576,

    ],
...
]
```

**Login Action**

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Login From**

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 3600 * 24 * 30);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cookie-based login.

For this first must enable `enableAutoLogin` params in `user` component.

And so need to have an `auth_key` field in user table. and override `getAuthKey`, `validateAuthKey` and some functions. be like this code:

```
<?php

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * Finds an identity by the given ID.
     *
     * @param string|integer $id the ID to be looked for
     * @return IdentityInterface|null the identity object that matches the given ID.
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }

    /**
     * Finds an identity by the given token.
     *
     * @param string $token the token to be looked for
     * @return IdentityInterface|null the identity object that matches the given token.
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }

    /**
     * @return int|string current user ID
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string current user auth key
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $authKey
     * @return boolean if auth key is valid for current user
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }
}
```

And for generate new `auth_key` for each user:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    ......

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if ($this->isNewRecord) {
                $this->auth_key = \Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I recommend you read all of this article for details:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html

Comment: Thank you, i wasn't implementing the getAuthKey method i added it and updated my DB but it didn't fixed the issue. also tried to add die() inside the getAuthKey method but it's seems that it's not called from anywhere !

Comment: @KhaledHasania `getAuthKey()` method call when you login.
Are you sure have `'enableAutoLogin' => true,` in user component in web config file?

Comment: I found the issue i wasn't selected the "auth_key" in the sql query so it was saved as null in the cookies. thank you for helping me.